# rich:message disables commandButton after first use

Tags: jsp, jquery, richfaces

after investigating the Internet for days, the problem still exists. I wonder if anyone could help me out, please.

A external login form is displayed by a jQuery overlay
http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/external.html

Username and password is requested through the form. rich:messages should display errormessages if necassary after pressing the submit-button. This works fine only one time. Without rich:message the submit works fine multiple times.
What I am doing wrong?
Some code:

Source code of overlay_login.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"    
<div id="overlay-content">
    <h1>Anmelden</h1>


    <h:form id="login_form">

        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['login.mainMailOrName']}" />
        <div id="overlay-panel">
            <h:inputText id="mainMailOrName" value="#{login.mainMailOrName}"
                required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['general.fieldRequired']}"
                size="30" />
            <rich:message for="mainMailOrName" />
        </div>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['general.password']}" />
        <div>
            <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{login.password}" size="30"
                required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['general.fieldRequired']}"
                validator="#{login.validPasswordValidator}"
                validatorMessage="#{msg['login.loginFailed']}" />
            <rich:message for="password" style="color:#aa0000;" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <a4j:commandButton  image="images/login_button.png" oncomplete="if(#{!facesContext.validationFailed}) $('a[rel]').overlay().close(); return false;" />
        </div>

    </h:form>
```

Comment: Disabled or not responding to clicks? You can use `<a4j:log>` to see what's happening with the latter.

Comment: after testing with <a4j:log>, I would say the button is not responding, because debug says: Similar request currently in queue

Comment: but what does it mean and how to prevent queue?

Comment: Ajax requests are placed in a queue, that's how it works. The error means the previous request did not finish correctly; I'm guessing there's an issue with execution scope. If you're using nested forms get rid of them (though that may not be what's causing the issue).

Comment: The session.bean which handle the login, is sessionscoped.

Comment: Without rich:message, there is no queuing - the request is finished. What makes the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved bei using `<h:message>` instead of `<rich:message>`

```
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
<!-- <rich:message for="mainMailOrName" style="color:#aa0000;" /-->
     <h:messages for="mainMailOrName" style="color:#aa0000;" />
</a4j:outputPanel>
```